# How to insert bold quote symbols in HTML

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts, symbols

I wanted to insert this bold ❝❞ as you can see on https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Work+Sans?preview.text=%E2%9D%9D%E2%9D%9E%20:
[image: The bold ❝❞]

To do that, I quickly came up with this:

```css
* {font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>❝ Something ❞</h1>
```

The problem is that when I run that code, it is this that is shown:

[image: It is not this that I want]

What am I missing? Oh, and when I go to [this](https://weiweihuanghuang.github.io/Work-Sans/) website, more symbols appear like the one below appear!

[image: This appeared as NOT a image]

[image: And all the symbols on this screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find out what's the Google Fonts problem but if you download their fonts form their [website](https://weiweihuanghuang.github.io/Work-Sans/) they should work properly.
 You can also find specific font weights that you need through Network tab in Inspect Elements

[image: Betworks element]

Answer (score 0):

You use font-size and use font-weight as you need or you can use icon for it.

Comment: Hey Rasel! That could be an option, but I think Google Fonts can not do that. Am I right?

Comment: Here is a screenshoot of Google Font's page: https://ibb.co/p4JBDZ8

Answer (score 0):

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>HTML</title>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
   b::before{
  content: "\201C"; 
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

b::after{
  content: "\201D"; 
  color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <p> there is <b>Something</b></p>
  <!-- Project -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>```
````